# How to search binary tree nodes to get longest tree in python using ADT

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

```
T = [[[[], [3, []]], [5, [[[[], [6, []]], [2, [[], [1, []]]]], [4, [[], [3, [[], [7, []]]]]]]]], [2, [[], [8, []]]]]
```

is a representation of a binary tree.

***THE ABOVE CODE FOR `T` IS LONG, SCROLL ACROSS FOR FULL CODE***

I am looking for the longest tree whose nodes sum is a multiple of a given number.

Example given `7` the tree `T` above as `searchMax(T, 7)`, `[[2,5], [4,3], [7]]` returns since it is the longest and also whose sum is a multiple of 7

[image: Pictorial representation]

I have defined the following code

```
def cons(x, y):
    return [x, y]

def car(p):
    return p[0]

def cdr(p):
    return p[1]

nil = []

def makeBinTree(root, left, right):
    return cons(left, cons(root, right))

emptyTree = nil


def isEmpty(tree):
    if len(tree) < 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def root(tree):
    return tree[1][0]

def left(tree):
    return tree[0][1]

def right(tree):
    return [1][1]

def searchMax(tree, number):
```

but I just don't know where to go from there. Can you please help me with this.

Comment: I notice that your `T` object contains no `8` values, but your diagram does contain an 8. For the sake of consistency, can you update `T` so it matches the contents of the diagram, or vice versa?

Comment: it does, its just long. If you scroll across  that section of the code you will see it.

Comment: @Kevin the scroll is there

Comment: Oops :-) thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Kevin any idea how to solve it?

Comment: What should the function do if there is more than one possible longest path? For example, Your tree has both `[[2,5], [4,3], [7]]` and `[[2,5], [4,2,1]]`. They both traverse over five nodes.

Comment: Yes `[4, 2, 1]` gives sum is 7 but it the final `[7]` which is what I am searching for is not in there. Remember `7` is the input so to get to `7` the method is go to where there are trees where the sum is a multiple of `7` until I get to `7`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183325/discussion-between-nicole-foster-and-kevin).

Answer (score 1):

I would write a function that iterates over all possible paths in the tree. Then I would iterate over those paths, and choose the ones that add up to a multiple of seven, and then from among those choose the longest one.

```
def isEmpty(tree):
    if len(tree) < 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def root(tree):
    return tree[1][0]

def left(tree):
    return tree[0]

def right(tree):
    return tree[1][1]

def iter_all_paths(t):
    if isEmpty(t):
        return
    yield [root(t)]
    for child in (left(t), right(t)):
        for path in iter_all_paths(child):
            yield [root(t)] + path

def searchMax(t, x):
    #find all paths that add up to a multiple of x
    candidates = []
    for path in iter_all_paths(t):
        if sum(path) % x == 0:
            candidates.append(path)
    if not candidates: 
        return None
    return max(candidates, key=len)

T = [[[[], [3, []]], [5, [[[[], [6, []]], [2, [[], [1, []]]]], [4, [[], [3, [[], [7, []]]]]]]]], [2, [[], [8, []]]]]
print(searchMax(T, 7))
```

Result:

```
[2, 5, 4, 2, 1]
```

This differs from your expected result, [2, 5, 4, 3, 7]. The two solutions have the same length so I assume it's fine to return one or the other. My solution returns the leftmost path if there is a tie in lengths.

---

Perhaps you're thinking "actually I don't want the longest path length, but rather the largest sum of nodes". Then [2, 5, 4, 3, 7] would beat [2, 5, 4, 2, 1] by seven. If that's what you want, you can change the final line of `searchMax` to `return max(candidates, key=sum)`.

---

You might also be thinking "I would prefer for the result to be a list of lists, not a list of ints. I want each sublist to add up to a multiple of the number. Rather than `[2, 5, 4, 3, 7]`, I want `[[2, 5], [4, 3], [7]]`.

You could write a function that arranges a list into chunks that add up to the number, and call that function before returning from `searchMax`.

```
def chunk(seq, x):
    result = [[]]
    for item in seq:
        result[-1].append(item)
        if sum(result[-1]) % x == 0:
            result.append([])
    if not result[-1]:
        del result[-1]
    return result

#later, in searchMax...
    return chunk(max(candidates, key=len), x)
```

Result:

```
[[2, 5], [4, 2, 1]]
```

Comment: but the sum if 4, 2, 1 does not give a multiple of 7

Comment: Yes `[4, 2, 1]` gives sum is 7 but it the final `[7]` which is what I am searching for is not in there. Remember `7` is the input so to get to `7` the method is go to where there are trees where the sum is a multiple of `7` until I get to `7`

Comment: Ok, if there is an additional requirement that the path must end with a 7, then you can change the conditional from `if sum(path) % x == 0:` to `if sum(path) % x == 0 and sum[-1] = 7:`

Comment: I get error `if sum(path) % x == 0 and sum[-1] == 7:
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: That's when the `chunk` and the `if sum(path) % x == 0 and sum[-1] == 7:` are added

Comment: Oops, I meant `path[-1]`.

Comment: if I search for 8 or another other number it gives me `None`

Comment: Sounds right to me. None of the paths in the tree add up to a multiple of eight.